# Is 'bol === !0' and 'bol == true' the same?

Tags: javascript

Is `bol === !0` exactly the same as `bol == true`?

**Example:**

```
function myFunction(bol){
    if(bol===!0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

alert(myFunction(true));//1
```

Will I ever run into problems if I decide to use it? (different than code readability)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which "equal" operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: I'm curious as to what this code is being used for?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL my question is not near close to that one

Comment: Don't use `!0` for `true` - a two-character saving is not worth the loss in readability. If you want `true` just say `true`.

Comment: Some JS compressors use `!0` and `!1` to save a couple bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `1 == true` is `true` but `1 === !0` is false.

Since `!0` is `true`, this is equivalent to `bol === true`. Note how you should still use the three equal signs to get exactly the same behavior.

The `===` means JavaScript will *not* try to coerce the values when comparing. If you actually *want* to coerce, you would use `==`. However, in this case, the `if` will just coerce for you:

```
if (bol) { ... }
```

is basically the same as

```
if (bol == true) { ... }
```

Comment: so `bol === !0` === `bol === true`?

Comment: Yes, because you evaluate `!0` first, which is equal to `true`.